# How get the ListItem from CheckBoxList that it's Selected property has changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, checkboxlist

I have a CheckBoxList and i want to get the ListItem when i select and deselect that item.I have tryed this solution

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem;
}
```

When i select an item,it will return that item.but when i deselect one item will return null(when any item is not selected) or another items (when there is another selected item).

How should i get the item that i have deselected now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a session variable that will keep track of currently selected items:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBoxList1.AutoPostBack = true;

    List<ListItem> selectedItems = Session["SelectedItems"] as List<ListItem>;
    if(selectedItems == null)
    {
        Session["SelectedItems"] = new List<ListItem>();
    }
}
```

Then every time selected items change you can compare previously selected items with new selected items and find out which item was selected or deselected:

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Gather currently selected items
    List<ListItem> newSelectedItems = new List<ListItem>();
    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected == true) 
        {
            newSelectedItems.Add(item);
        }
    }

    List<ListItem> oldSelectedItems = Session["SelectedItems"] as List<ListItem>;

    // Compare previous items count with current items count 
    // to find out whether item has been selected or deselected
    if (newSelectedItems.Count > oldSelectedItems.Count)
    {
        // Item has been selected
        ListItem selectedItem = newSelectedItems.Except(oldSelectedItems).First();
    }
    else
    {
        // Item has been deselected
        ListItem deselectedItem = oldSelectedItems.Except(newSelectedItems).First();
    }

    Session["SelectedItems"] = newSelectedItems;
}
```

Comment: I have used your solution,but i created `UserControl` ,but inestad of `Session` I use and static property.tankyou

Comment: And your answer have another problem,when I using data binding .

Answer (score 0):

I have created CustomControl Like this and used 'Krzysztof Bracha' solution .this way it simpler to use

UserControl:

```
public class JooyaCheckBoxList : CheckBoxList
{
    public JooyaCheckBoxList()
    {
        base.SelectedIndexChanged += JooyaCheckBoxList_SelectedIndexChanged;
        base.PreRender += JooyaCheckBoxList_PreRender;
    }

    private void JooyaCheckBoxList_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedItems = Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(li => li.Selected).ToList();
    }
    private static List<ListItem> SelectedItems { get; set; }
    private void JooyaCheckBoxList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ListItem> CurrentSelectedItems = Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(li => li.Selected).ToList();
        if (CurrentSelectedItems.Count > SelectedItems.Count)
        {
            var li = CurrentSelectedItems.Except(SelectedItems).SingleOrDefault();
            OnSelectedPropertChaned(li);
        }
        else if (CurrentSelectedItems.Count < SelectedItems.Count)
        {
            var li = SelectedItems.Except(CurrentSelectedItems).SingleOrDefault();
            OnSelectedPropertChaned(li);
        }
        else
        {
            OnSelectedPropertChaned(null);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<ListItem> SelectedPropertyChaned;
    public void OnSelectedPropertChaned(ListItem changedItem)
    {
        SelectedPropertyChaned?.Invoke(this, changedItem);
    }
}
```

and I used that like this:

```
    protected void cblKeywords_SelectedPropertyChaned(object sender, ListItem changedItem)
    {
            MessageDisplay= changedItem.Text + "  ||  " + changedItem.Value; 
    }
```